# How to copy rows from multiple csv files to new files in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, row

I have 10 csv files. I want to copy first row from all csv files and save as new csv file, then copy second row from all csv files and save as second csv file and etc. My code in the following done only for first row and other rwos display `NaN`. Where is my error?

**Code**

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime
import glob

path = r'/Jupyter_Works/new_csv'
all_files = glob.glob(path + "/*.csv")

date_time = datetime.datetime(2018, 1, 1)
index = pd.date_range(start='1/1/2018', periods= 8760, freq='H')

columns = ['Lat','Lon','Alt','Temperature','Relative Humidity','Wind speed','Wind direction','Short-wave irradiation']
dfcsv = pd.DataFrame(index=index, columns=columns)

for filename in all_files:
    df = pd.read_csv(filename, index_col='time', header=0)
    dfcsv.iloc[0] = df.iloc[0]

dfcsv
```

**Result**

```
Lat Lon Alt Temperature Relative Humidity   Wind speed  Wind direction  Short-wave irradiation
2018-01-01 00:00:00 31.03   49.36   99  285.56  52.82   2.95    128.5   0
2018-01-01 01:00:00 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
2018-01-01 02:00:00 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
2018-01-01 03:00:00 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
2018-01-01 04:00:00 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
```

Comment: Are the csv files of the same length eg: do they have the same amount of rows?

Comment: Hi @Erfan, Yes.

Comment: Do they already have the column names on the first row?

Comment: Yes, the column names are in the head of each csv file.

Comment: Last question, the length of the csv files is `8760` since you took that amount of periods for your index?

Comment: Yes, that's right. My data is hourly for one year (2018).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First create one big `DataFrame` with list comprehension and [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html), loop by unique values for select by `loc` and write to files by [`DataFrame.to_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html). It working, because each DataFrame has unique index, so if select by unique values then select rows with same position in all files.

```
path = r'/home/nickan/Jupyter_Works/new_csv'
all_files = glob.glob(path + "/*.csv")

dfs = [pd.read_csv(fp, index_col='time', parse_dates=['time']) for fp in all_files]
df = pd.concat(dfs)

for x in df.index.unique():
    #removed duplicated index by index=False
    df.loc[x].to_csv(f'csv/file_{x.strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H")}.csv', index=False)
```

EDIT:

Because memory problems is possible use alternative solution with loop by each row in dataFrames and write in append mode:

```
for i, fp in enumerate(all_files):
    df = pd.read_csv(fp, index_col='time', parse_dates=['time']) 
    for x in df.index:
        f = f'out/file_{x.strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H")}.csv'
        if i == 0:
            df.loc[[x]].to_csv(f, index=False)

        else:
            df.loc[[x]].to_csv(f, index=False,header=None, mode='a')
```

Comment: Hi @jezrael, this code has the error `ValueError: No objects to concatenate`.

Comment: @nickan - Is possible use gdocs, dropbox, wetransfer or similar for upload files and then share url link ?

Comment: Sorry @jezrael,https://drive.google.com/file/d/1JUwgpIhUZNGravmuktu9KOF7E0VPOFtq/view?usp=sharing
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1j9sRblqyIvX2lhFiXD48qwLBXddTPCK6/view?usp=sharing
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1dN47mqxdW_x3m4dzBaS9sls5FW_DkUvE/view?usp=sharing

Comment: ,what is the error `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'strftime'`?

Comment: thanks for your answer but I have error `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'strftime'` yet.

Comment: there is 980 files and it is not possible to share. I tested this code with 3 files that I have been shared, in another folder but the error not solved!

Comment: Yes. what is the deference between `df` and `dfs` in code?

Comment: @nickan - `dfs` is list of all DataFrames, `df` is  big dataframe after concat created from all small ones.

Comment: sorry new error,`'list' object has no attribute 'loc'`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193584/discussion-between-jezrael-and-nickan).